# How to detect recursion in Java methods

Tags: java, recursion

How can I check from inside a method body if a method that I call calls my method back?

```
// the method that I control
public void myMethod() {
     if( stackContainsMyMethod() ) {
        throw new RuntimeException("do not call me");
     } 
     ...
     handler();
}

// someone else implements this
protected abstract void handler();
```

The handler must not call **myMethod()**. I want to enforce this at runtime.

Can anyone help with a simple approach?

Comment: One screw ball way to do this would be just to set a global flag when its been called once and check for it again.

Comment: @noMAD Sounds more like you would need a counter to increment at the beginning of the method, and decrement when it returns. You haven't been called recursively if the counter is 1 (just yourself). NVM, didn't fully read the spec, actually wants to error on recursion, just thought maybe he wants to branch on that condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to look at the current stack trace and check for yourself:

```
StackTraceElement[] trace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();

for(int i=0; i < trace.length; i++) {
    //look for yourself and exit
}
```

Answer (score 7):

It's easier if you try to detect it only on the second round. Something like this should work.

```
boolean isRunning;

public void myMethod() {
    if (isRunning) {
        throw new RuntimeException("do not call me");
    }
    isRunning=true;
    handler();
    isRunning=false;
}
```

Comment: As long as there's only one thread in the program.  This will break down if `myMethod()` could be called simultaneously from multiple threads.

Comment: @ajb instead of ```boolean``` you would use ```ThreadLocal<Boolean>```. The advantage of this approach is a constant time of the check while what the accepted answer iterates the stack, possibly significantly increasing the execution time.

Answer (score 1):

IF your program is all synchronous, you can set a flag

```
bool calling = false;
public void myMethod() {

     if( calling ) {
        throw new RuntimeException("do not call me");
     } 
     calling = true;

...

    calling = false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it right with useSticks' answer like that:

```
public void myMethod() {
    final StackTraceElement[] trace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();

    for(int i=0; i < trace.length-1; i++) {
        if( trace[i].equals(trace[trace.length-1]) ) {
            throw new RuntimeException("do not call me again");
        }
    }

    handle();
}
```

thanks to all of you